# How to filter big CSV-file by highest humidity per day?

Tags: debian, scripting

I have millions of rows of this data, so I cannot do this operation by Spreadsheet. You see some data rows are without data so those should be skipped. The data is in .CSV format. Any Unix tools are welcome, maybe AWK since separator " ".

Something like

```
awk -F " " '{ print $1 $2 $3 $4}' filename.csv
```

but how to pick up the only the highest humidity per day.
One option but does not work:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 {next} {date=$1; humidity=$2; if (!max[date] || humidity > max[date]) {max[date]=humidity; line[date]=$0}} END {for (date in line) print line[date]}' filename.csv
```

Data (from Airthings View Plus -device)

```
recorded HUMIDITY %TEMP °C
2023-08-14 23:55:48 97.01 14.65
2023-08-14 23:55:50

2023-08-14 23:58:14 97.07 14.63
2023-08-14 23:58:16

2023-08-15 0:00:46 97.02 14.62
2023-08-15 0:00:48

2023-08-15 0:03:14 97.06 14.62
2023-08-15 0:03:16
```

REAL DATA by head

```
recorded,HUMIDITY %,TEMP °C
2023-08-14 16:55:56,97.64,14.62
2023-08-14 16:55:58,,
2023-08-14 16:58:13,97.41,14.76
2023-08-14 16:58:15,,
2023-08-14 17:00:45,97.04,14.88
2023-08-14 17:00:47,,
2023-08-15 17:03:12,96.78,15.26
2023-08-15 17:03:14,,
2023-08-15 17:05:45,96.59,14.89
```

Desired output

```
recorded HUMIDITY %TEMP °C
2023-08-14 23:58:14 97.07 14.63
2023-08-15 0:03:14 97.06 14.62
```

OS: Debian 12 Linux

Comment: I don't see any commas in your sample input. Are you sure it is csv file?

Comment: I imported the CSV file first to Excel and then here.

Comment: @elmo above see

Comment: If too large for spreadsheet, then time for data base. I use SQLite, and python to parse data both import & create reports. LibreOffice also has database, but I have not used it.

Comment: I believe this has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309882/how-do-you-do-a-bubble-sort-for-an-array-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

*Note: having now tried these with the OP's full `EX.3.feb.2024 - hum.t.p.day.csv` from google docs, the `csvsql` approach while aesthetically appealing appears to be **painfully** slow (approx. 600 times slower than the Miller solution).*

Given your example

```
$ cat input.csv
recorded,HUMIDITY %,TEMP °C
2023-08-14 16:55:56,97.64,14.62
2023-08-14 16:55:58,,
2023-08-14 16:58:13,97.41,14.76
2023-08-14 16:58:15,,
2023-08-14 17:00:45,97.04,14.88
2023-08-14 17:00:47,,
2023-08-15 17:03:12,96.78,15.26
2023-08-15 17:03:14,,
2023-08-15 17:05:45,96.59,14.89
```

then using `csvsql` from the Python-based [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
$ csvsql --query '
    SELECT recorded,MAX("HUMIDITY %") AS "HUMIDITY %","TEMP °C" FROM input \
    WHERE "HUMIDITY %" NOT NULL GROUP BY DATE(recorded)
' input.csv
recorded,HUMIDITY %,TEMP °C
2023-08-14 16:55:56.000000,97.64,14.62
2023-08-15 17:03:12.000000,96.78,15.26
```

For tabular output, pipe the result through `csvformat -T`.

---

Or using a decorate - sort - undecorate approach in [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
$ mlr --csvlite filter '!is_empty(${HUMIDITY %})' then \
    put '$day = splitnvx($recorded, " ")[1]' then \
    top -a -F -f 'HUMIDITY %' -g day then \
    cut -x -f day input.csv
recorded,HUMIDITY %,TEMP °C
2023-08-14 16:55:56,97.64,14.62
2023-08-15 17:03:12,96.78,15.26
```

If you want tabular output in this case, change `--csvlite` to `--icsvlite --opprint`.

Answer (score 2):

**AWK**

```
$ awk -F',' 'NR>1{arr[$1]=arr[$1]>$2?arr[$1]:$2} END{for (i in arr) print i "," arr[i]}' ~/test.txt
```

**Output**

```
2023-08-14,97.07
2023-08-15,99.06
```

**Input**

```
$ cat ~/test.txt
recorded,HUMIDITY,TEMPC
2023-08-14,97.01,14.65
2023-08-14,90.01,19.65
2023-08-14,97.07,14.63
2023-08-15,97.02,14.60
2023-08-15,97.06,14.68
2023-08-15,99.06,14.62
2023-08-15,59.06,10.62
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use sort command. Starting with your sample data:

```
$ cat infile
2023-08-14 23:55:48 97.01 14.65
2023-08-14 23:55:50

2023-08-14 23:58:14 97.07 14.63
2023-08-14 23:58:16

2023-08-15 0:00:46 97.02 14.62
2023-08-15 0:00:48

2023-08-15 0:03:14 97.06 14.62
2023-08-15 0:03:16
```

First get rid of the blank lines and short lines that do not have humidity and temperature data:

```
$ awk 'NF>2' infile
```

then pipe the result to a sort command:

```
$ awk 'NF>2' infile | sort -nr -t "," -k1,3
2023-08-15 0:03:14 97.06 14.62
2023-08-15 0:00:46 97.02 14.62
2023-08-14 23:58:14 97.07 14.63
2023-08-14 23:55:48 97.01 14.65
```

Comment: I got only header by this comman *$ awk 'NF>2' infile*. How should it work?

Comment: I put in the body CSV -version of the file

Answer (score 2):

On a GNU system such as Debian, you could do:

```
<your-file sort -k1,1 -k3,3rn | uniq -w10
```

Which sorts the input on the first column lexically and then on the third `n`umerically and in `r`everse. And then we extract unique lines looking only at the first 10 characters.

You'll likely want to remove the non-relevant lines (such as the headers or those blank lines) preferably before to save some effort which on your sample looks like it could be achieved with just `grep '^2'`.

```
<your-file grep '^2' | sort -k1,1 -k3,3rn | uniq -w10
```

To preserve the header, pass it along first:

```
{
  head -n 1
  grep '^2' | sort -k1,1 -k3,3rn | uniq -w10
} <your-file
```

Comment: This seems to work, I will be plotting it to test

Comment: Some sample: *recorded HUMIDITY % TEMP °C
2023-08-14 16:55:56 97.64 14.62
2023-08-15 0:00:46 97.02 14.62
2023-08-16 0:00:47 96.78 14.76
2023-08-17 0:00:49 97.1 14.88
2023-08-18 0:00:50 97.65 15
2023-08-19 0:00:51 97.37 14.82
2023-08-20 0:00:54 97.65 14.88
2023-08-21 0:00:54 96.75 14.58
2023-08-22 0:00:57 98.12 14.62
2023-08-23 0:00:57 99.48 15.26
2023-08-24 0:00:59 98.8 15.32
2023-08-25 0:01:02  
2023-08-26 0:01:02 98.2 15.62
2023-08-27 0:01:03 98.06 16.49*. Some gaps visible there. and the  heading at the end.

Comment: Just remove the non-relevant lines such as the header beforehand if they get in the way.

Comment: Here real sample of the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OhU6sOfRYgSr12woMVxFPL7sYKKudgeZFz6ETbBCCFw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: For some reason, there are blanks *2023-12-08 0:00,,*. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -MCSV::Parser -e 'my $file_handle = open $*ARGFILES, :r;     
                          my $parser = CSV::Parser.new(:$file_handle, :contains_header_row);  
                          my %accum;                                 
                          until $file_handle.eof {                   
                              my %ln-in = $parser.get_line();        
                              %accum.append: %ln-in{"recorded"}.words[0] => %ln-in{"HUMIDITY %"};  
                          };                                         
                          $file_handle.close;                        
                          put .key => .value.max for %accum.sort;'   file
```

Here's an answer written in Raku, a programming language in the Perl-family. Raku's `CSV::Parser` module is loaded at the command line, and input is read linewise.

First a `$file_handle` is declared, then a `$parser`. A final `%accum` hash is used to capture data. In the central `until` conditional statement, `get_line` reads-in lines until `eof`. For each line, the temporary `%ln-in` hash is deconstructed into a key/value pair, with the date recorded as `key` and the humidity as `value`. This key/value pair is `append`ed to the `%accum` hash.

In the final statement, the `%accum` hash is out`put` with only the `.value.max`.

Sample Output:

```
2023-08-14  97.64
2023-08-15  97.24
2023-08-16  97.33
2023-08-17  97.91
2023-08-18  97.83
2023-08-19  97.74
2023-08-20  97.85
2023-08-21  98.27
2023-08-22  99.79
2023-08-23  99.74
2023-08-24  99.24
2023-08-25  98.82
2023-08-26  99.34
2023-08-27  99.99
2023-08-28  99.95
2023-08-29  96.76
2023-08-30  99.93
2023-08-31  99.99
2023-09-01  99.99
2023-09-02  97.43
2023-09-03  97.85
2023-09-04  98.2
2023-09-05  98.42
2023-09-06  98.37
2023-09-07  97.78
2023-09-08  98.4
2023-09-09  98.68
2023-09-10  98.86
2023-09-11  99.06
2023-09-12  99.16
2023-09-13  99.26
2023-09-14  99.29
2023-09-15  98.66
2023-09-16  98.86
2023-09-17  98.95
2023-09-18  97.05
2023-09-19  98.59
2023-09-20  98.79
2023-09-21  99.08
2023-09-22  99.19
2023-09-23  99.34
2023-09-24  99.04
2023-09-25  98.83
2023-09-26  98.03
2023-09-30  97.06
2023-10-01  96.42
2023-10-04  95.12
2023-10-05  95.54
2023-10-10  89.17
2023-10-12  92.46
2023-10-28  61.28
2023-10-29  63.81
2023-10-30  72.65
2023-10-31  83.58
2023-11-01  80.13
2023-11-02  73.02
2023-11-03  84.29
2023-11-04  88.51
2023-11-05  88.78
2023-11-06  88.92
2023-11-07  88.42
2023-11-08  84.67
2023-11-09  82.41
2023-11-10  88.76
2023-11-11  88.49
2023-11-12  81.66
2023-11-13  77.46
2023-11-14  75.9
2023-11-15  68.31
2023-11-16  64.05
2023-11-17  58.46
2023-11-18  70.53
2023-11-19  74.63
2023-11-20  80.45
2023-11-21  68.86
2023-11-22  74.33
2023-11-23  78.19
2023-11-24  76.35
2023-11-25  53.12
2023-11-26  55.34
2023-11-27  53.97
2023-11-28  73.23
2023-11-29  73.78
2023-11-30  68.54
2023-12-01  65.52
2023-12-02  60.14
2023-12-03  57.08
2023-12-04  56.14
2023-12-05  58.63
2023-12-06  69.79
2023-12-07  71.09
2023-12-08  67.39
2023-12-09  64.75
2023-12-10  75.76
2023-12-11  74.33
2023-12-12  71.79
2023-12-13  68.64
2023-12-14  66.75
2023-12-15  67.56
2023-12-16  77.84
2023-12-17  78.79
2023-12-18  76.41
2023-12-19  79.71
2023-12-20  73.87
2023-12-26  70.58
2023-12-27  70.97
2023-12-28  73.21
2023-12-29  74.73
2023-12-30  73.81
2023-12-31  63.24
2024-01-01  53.16
2024-01-02  54.76
2024-01-03  55.39
2024-01-04  57.09
2024-01-05  54.78
2024-01-06  55.84
2024-01-07  49.51
2024-01-08  65.82
2024-01-09  76.71
2024-01-10  77.09
2024-01-11  77.02
2024-01-12  71.6
2024-01-13  69.29
2024-01-14  69.79
2024-01-15  69.02
2024-01-16  58.51
2024-01-17  64.79
2024-01-18  70.11
2024-01-19  69.38
2024-01-20  52.53
2024-01-21  67.66
2024-01-22  78.08
2024-01-23  79.02
2024-01-24  78.58
2024-01-25  78.84
2024-01-26  70.76
2024-01-27  74.59
2024-01-28  79.74
2024-01-29  79.76
2024-01-30  78.77
2024-01-31  80.31
2024-02-01  80.34
2024-02-02  74.42
```

Above the code accumulates multiple values-per-key, only outputting the `max` at the end. For truly massive files this might be a problem. As an alternative to be more memory-efficient, the Raku code `append`s the incoming row's key/value pair, then immediately checks if the `value` elements > 1. If so, those values are reduced to a single `max` value. The code below give the same Sample Output as above:

```
~$ raku -MCSV::Parser -e 'my $file_handle = open $*ARGFILES, :r;
                          my $parser = CSV::Parser.new( :$file_handle, :contains_header_row); 
                          my %accum; 
                          until $file_handle.eof() { given $parser.get_line() -> %ln-in {  
                              my $ln-key = %ln-in{"recorded"}.words[0]; my $ln-value = %ln-in{"HUMIDITY %"};
                              %accum.append: $ln-key => $ln-value;
                              %accum{$ln-key} = %accum{$ln-key}.max if %accum{$ln-key}.elems > 1 }
                         }; 
                         $file_handle.close; 
                         put .key => .value for %accum.sort;'  file
```

https://github.com/tony-o/perl6-csv-parser
https://raku.org